# Hyperledger Fabric without Docker on Local Machine Setup

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric. I need to set up the Hypeledger Fabric development environment on my local machine (Ubuntu 16). **As Fabric is dockerized**, I want to know how can I set it up on my local machine. I have tried searching for a tutorial but there isn't one.

I am making a production level project so I cannot rely on Docker, please guide me on local machine setup (*docker independent*).

*Hyperledger Fabric documentation is very user-friendly however it does not provide information on setting environments locally. Previous questions on Stack Overflow are not serving my purpose.*

Answer (score 6):

Based on this [Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) tutorial, you can extract these commands from shell script and docker-compose file, then run them on your local machine.

First, you must have two config files: `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml`. You can find them on the directory: `fabric-samples/first-network/`

Using `crypto-config.yaml` to generate the public key, private key, certificate and etc.

Consuming `configtx.yaml` file to generate genesis block and so on.

You can manually generate the certificates/keys and the various configuration artifacts using the `configtxgen` and `cryptogen` commands.

1)

```
# cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

2)

```
# export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
# mkdir channel-artifacts
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
# export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
```

3) configure `orderer.yaml` and  `core.yaml`, you can get it from [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.2/sampleconfig)

4) update these two file with real keys and certs.

5)

```
# orderer start
```

6)

```
# export set FABRIC_CFG_PATH = ${PWD}
# peer node start >> peerlog.log 2>&1 &
```

Up to now, the fabric network is on. Then you can create & join channel, or do other operations.

If you have any confision about this, let me know. Good luck.

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: Getting this error while channel creation after following above steps: `Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing`

Comment: I was able to start orderer and peer. tho I have not able to create a channel. it always fails to connect saying bad certificate and serverHandshake fails.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking but I put together a project https://github.com/chainforce/native-fabric that uses Fabric natively (on OSX) without even Chaincode container. A sample chaincode is written in Go and deployed with Go Plugin as a System Chaincode. You may find more info on System Chaincode from Fabric document, but basically it can do what Docker-based chaincode can do and more.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Fabric with Docker if you [deploy to production](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#docker-and-docker-compose). For testing purposes, you can follow [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) for a docker-free local version and can use [this](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/) for a docker-free browser version.

Comment: But using Docker for production level project would not be a prudent course of action. Why IBM Fabric does not provide document for local setup. Why using Docker even for production is viable.

Comment: IBM is more of a collaborator than anything, Hyperledger is pretty good with documentation so for future reference look there for docs. Local setup runs against your local storage so you wouldn't need Docker. Docker is just one of the more popular and well-documented container services, so it makes sense to use it. With proper security enabled on your webserver, Docker shouldn't pose as a problem in production-ready apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Fabric network on your local machine without Docker if fabric modules peer and orderer are compiled on your Ubuntu. In fact, local compilation is recommended in production.