# Hyperledger fabric and docker

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What is the need of docker in hyperledger fabric? Also why we need to run every process in different docker containers? Because It's putting extra overhead on the system.

Is there any alternative to docker in such scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger Fabric without Docker on Local Machine Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258985/hyperledger-fabric-without-docker-on-local-machine-setup). Because it’s so super easy to run anything with Docker.

Comment: But what is the benefits of using docker and how it simplify the network.?

Comment: The benefit is you don’t have to setup anything and it’s super easy to run. It’s also generally much more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Up to this date, Docker daemon is required for Fabric to run chaincode, and there is plan to eliminate this hard dependency. As for Fabric components, i.e. peer/orderer, it's just a process and you can run it however you want. Docker just helps developer to set up environment with ease (one can just pull images and run).