# Channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric (without Docker)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm having some troubles creating a channel in Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.3 without the use of Docker. I could succesfully generate keys, certs, genesis block and the various artifacts by simply executing `cryptogen` and `configtxgen`, then start orderer and peer. However, when I try to create a channel with command

`peer channel create -c mychannel -o 127.0.0.1:7050`

it fails due to `"BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating Readset: existing config does not contain element for [Group] /Channel/application/SampleOrg but was in the read set`.

Below the list of commands (executed from `fabric-samples/first-network` directory):

```
# cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

# export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
# mkdir channel-artifacts
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
# export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
# configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP

# sudo mkdir -p /var/hyperledger/production
# sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/hyperledger
# orderer start

# export set FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$HOME/fabric-samples/config
# peer node start >> peerlog.log 2>&1 &

# peer channel create -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
```

**This is the output of the the peer terminal, after the attempt of the channel creation:**

```
2019-10-01 12:51:11.955 CEST [ChannelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group] 
 /Channel/Application/Org1MSP but was in the read set
```

**In the orderer terminal, subsequently:**

```
2019-10-01 12:51:11.958 CEST [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 015 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 127.0.0.1:48526 because of error: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: existing config does not contain element for [Group] 
 /Channel/Application/Org1MSP but was in the read set
2019-10-01 12:51:11.958 CEST [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO016 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=127.0.0.1:48526 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.14698ms
2019-10-01 12:51:11.961 CEST [comm.deliver] Handle ->WARN017 Error reading from 127.0.0.1:48524: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-10-01 12:51:11.961 CEST [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 018 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=127.0.0.1:48524 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.834477ms
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've tried all the solutions I've found online. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

This is what I modified in orderer.yaml:

```
LocalMSPDir: /home/rfiorini/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp
```

This is what I modified in core.yaml:

```
mspConfigPath: /home/rfiorini/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp
```

Comment: What do mean by "without the use of docker"? What is your environment? Is it kubernetes?

Comment: I'm simple running commands extracted from the byfn.sh script, according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258985/hyperledger-fabric-without-docker-on-local-machine-setup. I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 in local.

Comment: Check your configtx.yaml, it is throwing an error because of channel configuration. Have you changed the configtx.yaml? Paste the configtx also.

Comment: I've only modified orderer.yaml and core.yaml. I've edited the question to add the modifications.